# Statements after while loop not executing

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am trying to remove a user from the mailing list right before I perform the emailing to my users. However, the code responsible for this within the second `while` loop is not executing.

Can somebody see why this is?

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM remove_request";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $query = "DELETE FROM mail_table WHERE first_name='" . $row["first_name"]
            . "' AND last_name='"     . $row["last_name"]
            . "' AND email_address='" . $row["email_address"] . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
        echo $row["first_name"] . ' has been removed from the mail list.';
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM mail_table";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database');
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        mail($row["email_address"],$subject,$message,$headers);
        echo 'email sent to ' . $row["first_name"] . "\n";
    }
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Did you check the output of ```result``` right before each loop?

Comment: ar4e you sure that you have any record in  your `remove_request` table?

Comment: You area changing `$result` inside the while.

Comment: @rray thank you for your comment, you are correct. I fixed the first while loop and everything is running fine now.